# What is the difference between android:layout_width and android:width

Tags: android, layout

I do not know the difference between these two attributes and for the height also.

Take a TextView for example, what would happen if I set its layout_width to wrap_content and set its width to 50 dip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is essentially no difference, only a TextView has the width property also.

[TextView.setWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:width)

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference when using it in combination with layout_weight to fill a parent layout.

When using layout_weight on a TextView you need to set android:width to 0dip. Setting android:layout_width to 0dip will not work.

Comment: Well setting `layout_width` to 0dp worked  for me just like `width`.