# How to give Fixed width and height for Button in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Im beginner in android development. I ve just created a button in main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



  <Button 
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

I just give integer value for android: but I got error 
error: Error: Integer types not allowed

How can give fixed width and height for Button here?
and
What is the main difference between  android:layout_width and android:Width?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn what the fields actually mean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a button with fixed height and width, you can give values in both px or in dp.

giving values in dp is more convenient , bec android automatically scale the height and width in ldpi,mdpi and hdpi devices.

```
<Button 
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    />
```

[What is the difference between android:layout_width and android:width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713795/what-is-the-difference-between-androidlayout-width-and-androidwidth)

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
<Button 
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

where dip is density indepedent pixel

Comment: for more on it please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Numeric Values as following,

```
 <Button 
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use integer(25, 40 ...) + type(DP,DIP,PX) :like

```
android:layout_width="25dp"
```

Why you want to do it . better use wrap content, or use weight tag, so it will support and will look good on all sizes devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need To give Like this

```
<Button android:layout_Width="150dp"
    android:layout_Height="50dp"  />
```