# Difference between android:width and android:layout_width

Tags: android, android-layout

in the following code why the appearance of the *radio button* changes when i set

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and

```
 android:width="fill_parent"
```

i am talking about the _radio button _ whose id is `left`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/orientation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5px" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"
        android:text="horizontal" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/vertical"
        android:text="vertical" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gravity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5px"

     >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:text="left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   // I am talking about this line
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:text="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:text="right" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713795/what-is-the-difference-between-androidlayout-width-and-androidwidth)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[android:width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#width) is for setting an exact number of pixels.

[android:layout_width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_width) can be a dimension, as above, or it can be one of `fill_parent`, `match_parent`, or `wrap_content`.

It is an error to use something other than a dimension for `android:width`.

Comment: but when i delete `android:width` the appearance changes ,, so it has effect

Comment: @HeshamAbouelsoaod Sorry, I didn't realize `RadioButton` was actually a subclass of `TextView`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: "width
added in API level 1
public int width
Information about how wide the view wants to be. Can be one of the constants FILL_PARENT (replaced by MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8) or WRAP_CONTENT, or an exact size."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#attr_android%3alayout_width