# EditText not WordWrapping in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an EditText field that I would like to have wrap text.

[image]

As you can see from the example above the text "Some place , 200 Dayton Ave Suite 200, Redbank, CA 37404 " gets cut off. It isn't behind the button. The EditText field stops where the map button starts. I can scroll to the right and see all the text. I would just like it to wrap two or 3 lines.

Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDestination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbEditDestination"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editDestination"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@color/COLOR_LIGHT_GREY"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="4"
            android:maxLines="8"
            android:minLines="4"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/editDestination"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/editDestination"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMapDestination"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/COLOR_BLUE"
            android:text="MAP"
            android:textColor="@color/COLOR_WHITE"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried in xml to add `android:singleLine="false"` for the EditText ?

Comment: I did not since it is deprecated

Comment: Change height of Editetxt to some value as of it is taking value of linear layout and add margin from right on edit text

Comment: I know, But give it a try, I think there is some issues that only solved by this lines.

Comment: Didn't work @OmarHossamEldin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294498/android-edittext-multiline-does-not-work-as-it-should may be this can help

Comment: I have tested code and it is working correctly! on android 7 Simulator