# when i'm creating a button it become different size in different mobiles why...?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i'm new to the android when i'm creating the button it's become variation in different mobiles please help me.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:width="300sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `dp` instead of `sp`

Comment: ude `dp` instead for button

Comment: Why do you define the button width twice? The second time with an exact width? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181971/difference-between-androidwidth-and-androidlayout-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

construct your button like below. Remove `android:width="300sp"`, It is not needed:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button         
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: then also i'm getting that Problem only i used DP instated of SP then also it is variations haveing

Comment: If you implemented the same as i have done above you will not have that problem..!! check it once i have updated with full code.. Just copy-paste it and see what happens..!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `sp` unit which is device independent BUT is scaled with the user's font size preference

Just use `dp` instead

Answer (score 0):

different mobile have a different density so that you button like small medium as per density

Answer (score 0):

Use dp instead of sp.
As per documentation
(https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
"you should prefer the sp (scale-independent pixel) to define text sizes. The sp scale factor depends on a user setting and the system scales "