# Differences and Same case of layout_width or layout_height, width, height

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-xml

is there any differences between `layout_(property)` and `(property)`, like `layout_width` and `width`? When defining styles, there are two properties of width or height. I heard that normal `width` and `height` will set the value as a Pixel. but can we use it with `layout_property`, setting the value as `px`?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181971/difference-between-androidwidth-and-androidlayout-width

Comment: In general you should never set `width` or `height`. You want to control tha layout of the `View` and to do that you use the `layout_*` properties. These values are used during the layout pass when determining the size and position of each `View` in the hierarchy. If you want to know more, have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws) or search for a description of how Android performs the layout of the `View` hierarchy.